# Error without log, EXC BAD ACCESS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

What does this error mean and how to handle it?

[image]

I suspect it happens when I load images from a web service with WEBClass and during that time I push some VC that needs other data from the WEBClass. This class is a shared instance. Could that be a possible reason?

Comment: Most likely, you're referencing a null pointer.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson, I suspect that it can be when I load some images from web service with WEBClass and in that time I push some VC that needs other data from WEBClass. WEBClass is shared instance. Is it possible to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the `Product` menu in `Xcode`, select `Edit scheme` and then choose the `Diagnostics` tab. There you have **`Enable Zombie Objects`**. Once selected and run, the debugger will point you to the object that is causing a trouble.

```
Product > Edit Scheme > Diagnostics > Enable Zombie Objects
```

And try to reproduce the crash.

Comment: I suspect that it can be when I load some images from web service with WEBClass and in that time I push some VC that needs other data from WEBClass. WEBClass is shared instance. Is it possible to be?

Comment: It is possible, but it's really hard to say. You need to provide more information about your problem.